# JAVA Drag and Drop Program not running smoothly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, drag-and-drop

so I will be creating a drag and drop program but before I start my main idea I have been practising my code. At the moment I simply just want to move a jlabel (that contains an image) around the screen. I have this working in a regular JAVA document, but cannot get code to work well under the netbeans design tool, (Trying to get it to work this way as I like the GUI editor).

Now the problem im having is while yes I can move the image it is far from smooth, it is very buggy jumps around quite a bit and stray away from the actual curse pretty badly. How can I fix this? I really want this code working through the design tool, below is my buggy code:

```
package moodrag;

public class noLag extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int mouseX , mouseY ;
    boolean mouseD;

    public noLag() {
        initComponents();
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        ball = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));    
        ball.setIcon(new                              javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/moodrag/ball.png"))); // NOI18N
        ball.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ballMouseDragged(evt);
            }
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ballMouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });    
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                .addComponent(ball)
                .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(ball)
                .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );    
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void ballMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       ball.setLocation(mouseX ,mouseY ); 
       mouseX = evt.getX();
       mouseY = evt.getY();
       mouseD = true;
    }                                 

    private void ballMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {           
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(noLag.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(noLag.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(noLag.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(noLag.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new noLag().setVisible(true);
            }`enter code here`
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel ball;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems jump out me immediatly.

1. The container in which `ball` resides is under the control of a layout manager, which means that the layout manager may choose to reset the location of the component at any time
2. The logic in `ballMouseDragged` seems backwards.  You're setting the location of `ball` to the previously known location of the mouse, not it's current location
3. The `MouseListener` is attached to `ball`.  This means that mouse events will be contextual to it (that is, the 0x0 will represent the top/left corner of the component (`ball`))

For example:

- [Drag and move a picture inside a JLabel with mouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130257/drag-and-move-a-picture-inside-a-jlabel-with-mouseclick/13131402#13131402)
- [JLabels, that store ImageIcons, are returned back to original location when the mouse is clicked in the panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145798/jlabels-that-store-imageicons-are-returned-back-to-original-location-when-the/13146002#13146002)
- [How to prevent JLabel positions from resetting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247833/how-to-prevent-jlabel-positions-from-resetting/21248274#21248274)